# Connection reset by peer when bulk loading data

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, database-connection

I am running the following method:

```
private static void bulkLoad() throws SQLException{
    final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
    final Statement s = connection.createStatement();
    s.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'LoadData.txt' INTO TABLE emails FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'");
}
```

But am inconsistently (sometimes I get it and sometimes I don't) getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 114,558 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 104,210 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3644)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendFileToServer(MysqlIO.java:3730)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2280)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2546)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:840)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:740)
    at SendEmailTools.bulkLoad(SendEmailTools.java:18)
    at SendEmailTools.main(SendEmailTools.java:110)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3625)
    ... 10 more
```

At first, I figured it may be a timeout issue, but I checked my `wait_timeout` and saw it is set to 28800, which should be more than enough time. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: The client is communicating with the server but server  closed connection because of error.

Comment: So how can I diagnose the error?

Comment: Examine stacktraces, find the root cause, change the code because you are doing wrong.